# How to display current parent active category and its sub-categories only in Sidebar?

Tags: shopware6

Hey I would like to display only active parent category and its available sub-categories in the category-tree in `storefront/layout/sidebar/category-navigation.html.twig`.
so if **category A** is selected then it should display all its subcategories.
example

**Category A**

- Category A.1
- Category A.2
- Category A.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will output the tree branch to the currently active category, as well as the links to its direct descendant categories.

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/sidebar/category-navigation.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_navigation_categories_list_entry %}
    {% if (item.category.id in activeResult.id) or (item.category.id in activeResult.path) or (item.category.parentId in activeResult.id) %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Update:** If you want to hide the parents up to the currently viewed category, this should do the trick.

```
{% block layout_navigation_categories_list_entry %}
    {% if item.category.id in activeResult.path %}
        {% block layout_navigation_categories_recoursion %}
            {% if item.category.id in activeResult.id %}
                {% set levelIncrement = 1 %}
            {% else %}
                {% set levelIncrement = 0 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/sidebar/category-navigation.html.twig' with {
                navigationTree: item.children,
                activeResult: activeResult,
                level: level + levelIncrement
            } only %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if (item.category.id in activeResult.id) or (item.category.parentId in activeResult.id) %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it still shows the root category on deeper level. how can i get rid of it?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that should skip output of the parents up to the currently viewed category.

Comment: Hello, At the deepest level where the child count is 0, how can I show its sibling categories which are available? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want to hide the parents up to the currently viewed category only for third level categories. How is this possible? For categories of the upper levels it should show all as usual.